npm install is not working on ubuntu, keeps hanging
when i try to install packages, npm install doesn't work and i have tried most solutions online and its still not helping. this is the log of the error
0 verbose cli /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/npm
1 info using npm@9.6.6
2 info using node@v20.2.0
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 2ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 1ms
5 timing config:load:file:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc Completed in 1ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 1ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 2ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 0ms
9 timing config:load:file:/home/wildone/Desktop/Mern-stack/.npmrc Completed in 0ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 4ms
11 timing config:load:file:/home/wildone/.npmrc Completed in 1ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 1ms
13 timing config:load:file:/home/wildone/.npm-global/etc/npmrc Completed in 0ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load Completed in 11ms
17 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 11ms
18 timing npm:load:mkdirpcache Completed in 0ms
19 timing npm:load:mkdirplogs Completed in 0ms
20 verbose title npm i express
21 verbose argv "i" "express"
22 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 1ms
23 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 3ms
24 timing npm:load:display Completed in 4ms
25 verbose logfile logs-max:10 dir:/home/wildone/.npm/_logs/2024-05-08T09_16_38_538Z-
26 verbose logfile /home/wildone/.npm/_logs/2024-05-08T09_16_38_538Z-debug-0.log
27 timing npm:load:logFile Completed in 8ms
28 timing npm:load:timers Completed in 0ms
29 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
30 timing npm:load Completed in 27ms
31 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 1ms
32 silly logfile start cleaning logs, removing 3 files
33 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
34 timing idealTree:init Completed in 15ms
35 timing idealTree:userRequests Completed in 4ms
36 silly idealTree buildDeps
37 silly fetch manifest express@*
38 silly logfile done cleaning log files
39 silly placeDep ROOT express@ OK for: mern-stack@1.0.0 want: *
40 timing idealTree:#root Completed in 88226ms
41 timing idealTree:node_modules/express Completed in 0ms
42 timing idealTree:buildDeps Completed in 88227ms
43 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
44 timing idealTree Completed in 88249ms
45 timing command:i Completed in 88264ms
46 verbose type system
47 verbose stack FetchError: request to http://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: Socket connection timeout
47 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/minipass-fetch/lib/index.js:130:14)
47 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:511:28)
47 verbose stack     at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:495:9)
47 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (node:events:523:35)
47 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
47 verbose stack     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
47 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
48 verbose cwd /home/wildone/Desktop/Mern-stack
49 verbose Linux 6.5.0-28-generic
50 verbose node v20.2.0
51 verbose npm  v9.6.6
52 error code ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
53 error errno ERR_SOCKET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
54 error request to http://registry.npmjs.org/express failed, reason: Socket connection timeout
55 verbose exit 1
56 timing npm Completed in 88492ms
57 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1715159798761
58 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1715159798770
59 verbose code 1
60 error A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/wildone/.npm/_logs/2024-05-08T09_16_38_538Z-debug-0.log

i tried uninstalling npm and its reponds with "package not installed" but if i check for the current version, it responds with the version number.
secondly, i tried changing the npm config mintimeout and maxtimeout, no effect.
i just want to be able to install packages.

You can install nvm on ubuntu and version node https://monovm.com/blog/install-nvm-on-ubuntu/
